# Singular continuous random variable multiplied by a constant

Tags: probability-theory

If we multiply a singular continuous random variable by a positive constant, is the resulting random variable also singular continuous?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "singular"?

Comment: $\mu$ is singular continuous if $\mu\{x\}=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
but there is $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(S)=0$ and $\mu(S^{c})=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Let $X$ be a singular continuous random variable with CDF $F$. Then $F$ is a [singular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function) continuous function. Fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a>0$ for simplicity. Denote the CDF of $aX$ by $F_a$. For $t\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$F_a(t)=\mathbb{P}[a X\leq t]=\mathbb{P}\left[X\leq \frac{t}{a}\right] = F(t/a)$$

So $F_a$ is continuous.

The derivative of $F$ vanishes almost everywhere, so the same holds for $F_a$, by a little analysis. Hence $F_a$ is singular.

So $aX$ is a singular continuous random variable.